# Objective-c method call passing a reference to the caller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, methods, parameters

When using a UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method then the tableview that called the method is passed to the method itself:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

How can I create a method call signature that leverages the same technique, so I can pass the caller to a method?  Something like this:
Signature:

```
- (void)questionDelegate:(HPSPickAWinnerQuestionDelegate *)questionDelegate questionDidChange:(NSInteger)questionElementTag
```

Call:

```
[self.pickAWinnerDelegate questionDidChange:2];
```

But this doesn't work - what is the correct syntax?

Many thanks.

Comment: Research the delegate pattern, it is a fundamental aspect of objective-c

Comment: Thanks Simon.  My understanding is that my class is acting as a delegate, and I want the method to be able to reference the object that is calling the delegate method.  I just wondered what the syntax would be to mimic what Apple seem to be doing.  Or am I way off? :)

Comment: If I create a UITableView and from inside that class i want to pass a reference to the calling instance i pass back 'self' to a parameter defined as the class type i.e. UITableView. I didn't tell you to look at the delegate pattern just for the hell of it. This is an integral part of the pattern, and programming in general. Any tutorial would have shown you this. One of the most important parts of being a developer is learning to research / learn new things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that you call will be called *on* a delegate, not passing a delegate as an argument. Here is a quick example for you:

```
@protocol HPSPickAWinnerQuestionDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)asker:(YourQuestionAskingClass *)asker questionDidChange:(NSInteger)questionElementTag;
@end

@interface YourQuestionAskingClass : NSObject
@property (weak) id<HPSPickAWinnerQuestionDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation YourQuestionAskingClass
- (void)someMethod {
  [self.delegate asker:self questionDidChange:2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self questionDelegate:pickAWinnerDelegate
     questionDidChange:2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method has 2 parameters.Maybe you should do like this:

```
[self questionDelegate:self.pickAWinnerDelegate questionDidChange:2];
```